# Why do we need a volume option in docker-compose when we use react/next?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, next.js

I have a question, why do we need to use `VOLUME` option in our docker-compose when we use for `React/Next.js` ?

If I understood, we use `VOLUME` to "save the data", for example when we use database.

But with `React/Next.js` we just use to pass the `node_modules` and `app path`, for me it does not make any sense...

If I put this:

```js
version: '3'
services:
  nextjs-ui:
    build:
      context: ./
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: nextjs-ui
    volumes:
       - ./:/usr/src/app/
       - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

It works..

If I put this:

```js
version: '3'
services:
  nextjs-ui:
    build:
      context: ./
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: nextjs-ui
```

It works in the same way..

Why do we need to save `node_modules` and `app path` ?

My DOCKERFILE:

```js
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001


COPY . .

EXPOSE 9000

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Need to see your `Dockerfile` to answer this. Usually we build the reactjs app and include only the build output in the docker image.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha Hiii, nice, I updated, I put the dockerfile, thanks

Comment: These `volumes:` declarations aren't necessary and can safely be removed.  They can cause problems like running untested code in production or Docker ignoring changes to your `package.json` file.  You can use a host Node environment for day-to-day development with live reloading while you're trying to make your unit tests work, and then package the working application in Docker for integration testing and deployment.

Answer (score 3):

As per your `Dockerfile`, it's already copying your source code and does a `npm run build`. Finally it run `npm start` to start the development server (this is not recommended for production).

By mounting `src/app` and `src/node_modules` directories, you get the ability to reload your app while you make changes to the source in your host machine.

In summary, if you did not mount the source code, you have to rebuild the docker image and run it for your changes to be visible in the app. If you mounted the source and node_modules, you can leverage the live reloading capability of `npm start` and do development on host machine.

Comment: Thank so much my friend, I appreciate your answer.. just a little question.. why the steps on Dockerfile are not recommended for production? What do you think that I have to change ?

Comment: Because, `npm start` starts a development server and it is not capable enough to handle a production traffic. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ for their recommended approach. You simply have to do install `serve` and serve the `build` directory which is created after the `npm run build` step.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha, There's a difference between create-react-app's ```start``` script and the one of Next.js. The Next.js ```start``` script starts the app in production mode according to the docs.

Answer (score 2):

With the volumes included, you reflect all your local changes inside your dockerized Next application, which allows you to make use of features such as **hot-reloading** and not having to re-build the Docker container just to see the changes.

In production, you do not have to include these volumes.

Comment: Thank so much for your time and your answer, helped me a lot!!!